# Cómo hacer evento click en un componente creado bajo el esquema de composisión

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, eventos

soy nuevo en react y no encuentro la forma de manejar un evento de click en este componente.

```
const Credit = props => (
  <Card>
   <div className="Credit">
     <img className="icon" src="/icons/money.svg" alt="icono dinero" />
     <p>{props.title}</p>
     <p><span>{props.money}</span></p>
     <ButtonNice onClick={handleClick}>
       {props.button}
     </ButtonNice>
</div>
```

);

Soy nuevo en react y es la primera vez que manejo un evento de click, 
todos los eventos de click en la documentación y en cualquier página usan el paradigma de herencia.

este es el ejemplo que viene en la documentación de react

```
class SignUpDialog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSignUp = this.handleSignUp.bind(this);
  this.state = {login: ''};
}

render() {
  return (
    <Dialog title="Mars Exploration Program" 
       message="How should we refer to you?">
      <input value={this.state.login}
           onChange={this.handleChange} />

    <button onClick={this.handleSignUp}>
      Sign Me Up!
    </button>
  </Dialog>
);
}

handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({login: e.target.value});
}

handleSignUp() {
  alert(`Welcome aboard, ${this.state.login}!`);
}
```

}

Existe una forma de manejar clicks sobre mi componente basado en composición?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i managed to find how to do it.

caveat, you can't pass an event handler directly to the component.

i need to pass it as a prop

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('hi');
};

const Credit = props => (
  <Card>
    <div className="Credit">
      <img className="icon" src="/icons/money.svg" alt="icono dinero" />
      <p>{props.title}</p>
      <p><span>{props.money}</span></p>
      <ButtonNice clickHandler={handleClick}>
        {props.button}
      </ButtonNice>
    </div>
  </Card>
);
```

then in my component receive the prop which is the function handling the click

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import './ButtonNice.scss';

const ButtonNice = props => (
  <button onClick={props.clickHandler} className="ButtonNice btn-transparent">
    {props.children}
  </button>
);

ButtonNice.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  clickHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default ButtonNice;
```

Comment: hello this is es.stackoverflow.com , so you shoud answer in spanish

Comment: Si es cierto @Daniel Pérez, es la costumbre cuando estoy en stack overflow me pongo en modo inglés.